# output raw field value with field_view_field in node template

Tags: nodes, theming

I'm trying to output just the raw value of a field in my node template. When I use 'field_view_field' it puts a ton of css classes around the value which breaks my styles. I just want the value. There must be a way to do this? Is there an option in the field_view_field array I can just call to turn off all the junk?

Comment: There is a very similar question in the "cousin site" StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694770/print-drupal-field-view-field-value-only . Would it be appropriate for you?

Comment: ah yes did work, thought I tried that! Thanks. Think maybe the array shift thing put me off, that can't be the 'correct' way to do it?

Comment: You are welcome! Getting the first element of an array with array_shift is a very common PHP idiom, as far as I know. There are some alternatives that don't modify the array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-the-first-element-of-an-array

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a 'Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in include() (line... warning from this that doesn't seem right. Do you know wy this might be?